# Beamer: how to skip only some `notes' frames

Tags: beamer, page-breaking

I'd like to hand out a printout of some slides, including some printed
notes and a bit of space for handwriting. The following is (more or less)
working:

```
\documentclass[handout,notes]{beamer}
  \usepackage{pgfpages}

  \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}
  \AtBeginSection[]{\frame{\Huge\insertsectionhead}}
  \AtBeginNote{Notes:\par}

  \makeatletter
    \def\beamer@framenotesbegin{% at beginning of slide
      \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}%
      \gdef\beamer@notes{{}}% used to be totally empty.
    }
  \makeatother

\begin{document}
  \section{1st section}
  \frame{The first slide\note[item]{With a note}}
  \frame{The second, and last, slide}
\end{document}
```

The `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` fragment makes every *normal* frame
being followed by a *notes* frame.  With `pgfpages`, each frame and its
note frame are printed on the same page.  Finally, each section gets its
own frame (`\AtBeginSection`).

**But** I don't want the *section* frame to be followed by a *notes*
frame, as is currently happening.  I've unsucessfully tried to:

- Make `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` check (with `\ifx`...?)
  whether it's being used from within a *normal* frame, or not.  The
  problem is that I don't know what condition could be used to tell if
  this is a normal page, a sectioning one, or whatever.
- Force, with `pgfpages`, a blank page; thus, the *section* frame and
  the blank page will be printed on the same page.

Some more details: I'm using org-mode within Emacs to write the slides.
Also, I'm using Beamer's command `\AtBeginNote` to heavily customize the
appearance of the *notes* frames (thus, I can't simply drop the
`\AtBeginNote` line).

Any ideas?  Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following basically takes the idea of Gonzalo, but puts everything you need into the `\AtBeginSection` command:

```
\documentclass[handout,notes]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}
\AtBeginSection[]{\setbeameroption{hide notes}\frame{\Huge\insertsectionhead}\frame{}\setbeameroption{show notes}}
\AtBeginNote{Notes:\par}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{% at beginning of slide
  \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}%
  \gdef\beamer@notes{{}}% used to be totally empty.
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{1st section}
\frame{The first slide\note[item]{With a note}}
\frame{The second, and last, slide}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Daniel!  You're right, this is sligthly more compact (thus I've flagged this as the preferred response).

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the notes before the section frame and then show them again:

```
\documentclass[handout,notes]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}
\AtBeginSection[]{\setbeameroption{hide notes}\frame{\Huge\insertsectionhead}}
\AtBeginNote{Notes:\par}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{% at beginning of slide
  \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}%
  \gdef\beamer@notes{{}}% used to be totally empty.
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{1st section}\frame{}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\frame{The first slide\note[item]{With a note}}
\frame{The second, and last, slide}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks (gracias) Gonzalo!  Your solution looks simpler, and more elegant, than that I was trying to do.